# Definition of a definable set of a substructure

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $M$ be a structure. Let $N$ be a substructure of $M$ (not necessarily an elementary substructure). Is it the case that every definable set $Y\subseteq$ $N^n$ in $N$ can be written as $Y=X\cap N^n$ where $X\subseteq M^n$ is a definable set in $M$?

Comment: What do you mean by definable? With or without parameters?

Comment: What if $M=(\mathbb R,\lt)$ and $N=[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup[4,5]\cup\cdots$? So $Y=\{1,3,5,\dots\}$ is definable in $N,$ right? Elements having an immediate successor? Now what subsets of $M$ are definable?

Comment: @bof: *Much* better example than mine!

Comment: @bof: regarding your first comment, yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @bof: regarding your second comment, by definability of a set _W_ of a structure _M_ I mean:

the smallest set _W_ that contains all the basic definable sets of _W_ (the singletons {c} for all the constants c of the signature of M, the intepretations of the predicates, and the graphs of the functions) and all the sets obtainable by the following three operations: "cylindrification", boolean operations and projections. 

(Should I write it down in the question?)

Comment: So you mean definable *without parameters*? That's all I was wondering about.

Comment: @bof: yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @bof: do you think that the statement holds if N is an elementary substructure of M?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

It turns out that $\Bbb Z$ is definable in $\Bbb Q$ when consider it as an ordered field. However, a definable subset of $\Bbb R$ (when considered as an ordered field) is a finite union of intervals, therefore $\Bbb Z$ is not definable there.

In particular, there is no set of real numbers $A$ which is definable over $\Bbb R$ in the language of ordered fields, and $A\cap\Bbb Q=\Bbb Z$.

---

Under the assumption that the substructure is an elementary submodel, we actually do get this. In fact, here is a very nice observation I realized now:

> **The following are equivalent:**
>
> 1. $N\prec M$.
> 2. If $A\subseteq M^n$ is definable by $\varphi$ in $M$, then $A\cap N^n$ is definable by $\varphi$ in $N$.

*Proof.*

Assume $N\prec M$, and $A=\{\bar m\mid M\models\varphi(\bar m)\}$. Then given any $k$-tuple from $N$, $\bar n$, $\bar n\in A\cap N^k$ if and only if $M\models\varphi(\bar n)$ if and only if $N\models\varphi(\bar n)$. So we get the wanted equality.

On the other hand, if we have relativization, suppose that $\bar n$ is a $k$-tuple from $N$, then for all $\varphi$, let $A_\varphi^M\subseteq M^k$ be $\{\bar m\mid M\models\varphi(\bar m)\}$, then $A_\varphi^N=A_\varphi^M\cap N^k$ and therefore $M\models\varphi(\bar n)$ if and only if $N\models\varphi(\bar n)$.

So your requested property is almost stating that $N$ is an elementary submodel of $M$. But it certainly holds for an elementary submodel.

Comment: Thanks. So my original statement does not even hold for elementary substructures, right?

Comment: No, it's true for elementary submodel. I will update my answer with a nice proof in a little while.

Comment: Okay, I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: yes it is. Thank you!

Comment: My edit was for a typo. ( A stray " \  " was removed.)